# how to run nodejs in google compute engine external ip with 2 separate port

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine

I'm facing an issue.

I have created vm instance on google compute engine. vm instance external ip is: 104.198.225.177. accessed ssh and installed nodejs. now I want to run 2 nodejs script one in port 8000 another in port 9000.

if want to run and access 2 nodejs url like this: `http://104.198.225.177:8000` and `http://104.198.225.177:9000`

I have created script but when I start and try to access in browser using vm instance external ip, like : `http://104.198.225.177:3000/` but its not working. I tried in ssh cur like : `curl localhost:3000/` and its working but using external ip its not working.

when I add ip address while starting nodejs like this: 
`app.listen(9000,"104.198.225.177");` I'm getting this error:
`listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 104.198.225.177:9000 at Object.exports._errnoException`

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ensure that you've allowed traffic from external sources to reach certain ports of your GCE instances in Networking [Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/#firewall_rules) section.

**Solved**: Also ensure that your application is bound to 0.0.0.0/all interfaces and addresses, not just VMs public IP address.

Comment: here is my firewall rule:
**Name | Targets | Source filters | Protocols / ports | Action | Priority |  network**
default-allow-http |  Apply to all | IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 |   tcp:80,8000,9000 | Allow  | 1000 | default

Comment: when I add ip address while starting nodejs like this: 
`app.listen(9000,"104.198.225.177");` I'm getting this error:
`listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 104.198.225.177:9000 at Object.exports._errnoException`

Comment: @RavendraPatel: you need to bind your application to 0.0.0.0 or internal GCE instance IP address. It would be still reachable from the outside - that is due to how public IP address routing is implemented in GCE.

Comment: can you please guide me how to bind application with 0.0.0.0 or internal ip. my vm instance internal ip is : 10.128.0.2

Comment: Ok got, its working now. I have used : `app.listen(9000,'0.0.0.0')` accessed from browser : http://104.198.225.177:9000/

and its working. Thank you so much.

Comment: @IlyaZakreuski could you describe what rules are necessary, in addition to linking to the page? From comments in seems this answer is not entirely clear. :)

Comment: @DonMcCurdy: 1 - specific rules would depend on the application, see first comment for this particular situation, 2 - core issue here was to bind the app to all interfaces/addresses, i.e. address 0.0.0.0. 3 - consider asking a separate question if you'd like to clarify something.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this same problem in my `Google Cloud Engine Instance (VM Instance)`.

The error was:

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 34.19.24.199:3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1446:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1511:12)
    at doListen (node:net:1660:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1490:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  errno: -99,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '34.19.24.199',
  port: 3000
}
```

And I followed the comment of @PrecariousJimi and @Pawan-Developers and Resolved that problem. But got confused that how to follow steps to resolve.
So, here I mentioned how you can resolve this issue if you face.

**STEP -1:** Go to firewall ([Firewall link](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-security/firewall-manager/firewall-policies)) in console and create a new policy with following details:

Name: `default-allow-http-traffic`

Network: `default`

Priority: `1000`

Direction of traffic: `ingress`

Action on match: `Allow`

Source filters: `0.0.0.0/0`

Protocols and ports: `all`

Now click on `Create` button.

**STEP-2:** Go to your `index.js` or `app.js` whatever your file name and change hostname to internal IP address which will provided aside External IP of Instance or `0.0.0.0` as below

```
const http = require('node:http');
const hostname = '10.129.0.2'; // In my case, Internal IP address works!!
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});
server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

**STEP-3:** run your file

```
sudo node index.js
```

Your node JS script will run on your External IP address with specified PORT:
Example:

```
http://34.19.24.199:3000
```

**STEP-4:** If node app still not showing. Allow your Instance firewall to port 3000 in the Virtual machine.

Run the below command in Virtual Instance.

```
sudo ufw allow 3000:3007/tcp
sudo ufw allow 3000:3007/udp
```

this will allow from 3000 to 3007 port for UDP and TCP

I hope this helps someone...